# Delta wing flow patterns (straight and yawing)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

I was wondering the differences between fluid patterns and their consequences when a delta wing is straight and yawed slightly.

Comment: Would [aviation.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many resources on the web which help to answer this question, but not necessarily very recent ones. Take [NACA TN 2674](http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/reports/1952/naca-tn-2674.pdf) which shows tufted delta wings, or [NACA Research Memorandum L57A30](http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/reports/1957/naca-rm-l57a30.pdf).

Generally, a delta wing shows separating flow at the leading edge beginning at moderate angles of attack. This separation leads to the formation of a vortex which is first close to the leading edge and moves inwards, becoming stronger, at increasing angle of attack. In sideslip, the leading half of the wing behaves like one with less sweep, and the reverse happens on the retreating half. This results in a lift difference, such that the wing rolls away from the sideslip (it lifts the leading half).